# Retrieving SQL enum causes java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, jpa

I have a query like this

```
Query importQuery = advertiserDao.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
    "select matching_type from group_key where key_id = " + Key.getkeyId());
String match = (String) importQuery.getSingleResult();
```

The `matching_type` is a `enum('good', 'bad', 'repared')` type. This gives an exception as following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What does it mean, the actual value is a string. How can I solve this?

Comment: it seems matching_type is varchar with length 1, I

Comment: its a enum type sorry did not mention before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to user a java.lang.Character variable as suggested by the exception:

```
Character match = (Character) importQuery.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. According to the official documentation, a MySQL ENUM type should definitely be returned as a String (actually, any MySQL data type can be converted to a `String`):

> ### [21.4.4.3. "Java, JDBC and MySQL Types"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)
>
> MySQL Connector/J is flexible in the
>   way it handles conversions between
>   MySQL data types and Java data types.
>
> In general, any MySQL data type can be
>   converted to a `java.lang.String`, and
>   any numeric type can be converted to
>   any of the Java numeric types,
>   although round-off, overflow, or loss
>   of precision may occur.
>
> Starting with Connector/J 3.1.0, the
>   JDBC driver will issue warnings or
>   throw DataTruncation exceptions as is
>   required by the JDBC specification
>   unless the connection was configured
>   not to do so by using the property
>   jdbcCompliantTruncation and setting it
>   to `false`.
>
> The conversions that are always
>   guaranteed to work are listed in the
>   following table:
>
> #### Connection Properties - Miscellaneous.
>
> ```
> These MySQL Data Types           | Can always be converted to these Java types
> ---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
> CHAR, VARCHAR, BLOB, TEXT, ENUM, | java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream,
> and SET                          | java.io.Reader, java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob
> ---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> The `ResultSet.getObject()` method
>   uses the type conversions between
>   MySQL and Java types, following the
>   JDBC specification where appropriate.
>   The value returned by
>   `ResultSetMetaData.GetColumnClassName()`
>   is also shown below. For more
>   information on the `java.sql.Types`
>   classes see Java 2 Platform Types.
>
> #### MySQL Types to Java Types for ResultSet.getObject().
>
> ```
> MySQL Type Name             | Return value of    | Returned as Java Class
>                             | GetColumnClassName | 
> ----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
> ...                         | ...                | ...
> ----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
> ENUM('value1','value2',...) | CHAR               | java.lang.String
> ```

I suspect a JDBC driver bug. What version are you using? Can you try with a more recent version? Does in work with raw JDBC?